# What is the appropriate HTTP request to get a random resource and reduce player's money?

Tags: rest, http, webserver, restful-architecture

I have a API to allow players to "explore" a region, which randomly returns a resource. Such action would cost some game currency, so the player information is updated as a result. Because the client uses this API to "get" some resource, it's natural to think that it should be an HTTP GET. However, a GET should be idempotent, and this is not. According to RFC 7231:

> The POST method requests that the target resource process the
>   representation enclosed in the request according to the resource's own
>   specific semantics.

and

> The PUT method requests that the state of the target resource be
>   created or replaced with the state defined by the representation
>   enclosed in the request message payload.

The fact that both requests are for processing enclosed payload makes them not very suitable in my case. What should I use?

Answer (score 1):

Actually this type of action doesn't really fit REST. I'd say it's more of a RPC method because you're defining an action, not a resource. RPC methods are generally POST, so in my opinion that's the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

(a) Don't look at RFC 2616 anymore; in this case what's relevant is RFC 7231.

(b) If no more specific method works for you, POST is your friend.

Comment: If I define the API like `POST /regions/:id/explore`, is it still considered RESTful?